# Fisher Test and corrections for multiple comparisons

Tags: multiple-comparisons, fishers-exact-test, bonferroni

When I do 4 comparisons (namely 4 groups of data) using Fisher test, do I have to correct the results for multiple comparisons (therefore reducing the accepted p for significance to everything below 0.0125)?

Is it something that I am required to do, or IN PARTICULAR WITH THIS TEST, is there a way to avoid it?

Comment: What are the four groups? Are they separate data-sets testing the same hypothesis?